# Не могу выполнить проверку is_array

Tags: twig

Есть такая конструкция на php, мне нужно ее реализовать на twig

```
  <?php foreach($params as $key => $val) { ?>
    <?php if (is_array($val)) { ?>
      <?php foreach($val as $value) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"/>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Но ни как не могу выполнить проверку is_array не могу придумать как ее в twig прописать.

Может кто знает как прописать? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `{% if val is iterable %}`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все заработало, как вы написали.